# c# Excel 2007 Addin - install on other pc

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, add-in

I create a software with vs2010. Its an Excel 2007 add-in. 
Its working perfectly. 
But I want to install it on another pc. All installer packgage installed without error. I added the .vsto file, but it isn't working, just "Inactive Plugin"...

I followed step-by-step the official [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332051.aspx) and unofficial but full [vsto-installer](http://www.clear-lines.com/blog/post/create-excel-2007-vsto-add-in-msi-installation.aspx) article write. But it isn't working. The install step ran successfully. All needed packages installed (vsto4.0, .net framework, interop office) and if I add the .vsto via double-click self-install, it is running correctly. But - as I wrote at the beginning - it isn't working, the vsto addin lists as an inactive plugin.

What did I do wrong, how can I install the vsto on another pc?

**UPDATE**
I found the answer. Just simple re-install the whole pc (windows, office) then its gonna work. So the problem not just the installer was, the system integration too.

I try the OneClick solution too, its work too. 
At msdn (links at up) sol very important the correct register keys and correct installer-pre-req (if something missing its never run/installed correctly).

Comment: If the add-in throws an exception at the start-up, word will deactivate it. Do you have some exception-logging in place, is it logging anything?

Comment: No, this isnt logging anything, just inactive in excel component/plugin list, and it isnt start, so its dont create any log (i put it in lot of debug solution). If i simple build on a pc via vs2010 its turn on, and work correctly, but i cant add it to other pc's excel... )

Comment: If you can, I would recommend to use ClickOnce to install your add-in, it's much easier than the msi approach.

Comment: I found some minor bug, i recommend for everyone to use lot of try-catch and handle unhandled-exceptions. It should be fix some bugs like in my app.